# Start HTML5 SVG animation in a dynamically-created <use> element

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I'm adding an SVG figure dynamically each time an external event occurs, with animation at the time of addition. I wrapped the figure in a <symbol> tag to give it its own viewbox, so that the animation transforms are independent of where the figure is placed.

Because the real figure and animation is more complex than those in the example below, I would like to define the figure and animation in HTML and dynamically create a <use> element to instantiate the figure each time it is added; rather than dynamically create the figure and animation in Javascript.

Creating the <use> element in Javascript and adding it to the <svg> element causes the figure to appear, but the animation does not run unless the figure is added right at page load time.  I could not find a value for the "begin" attribute that would trigger SVG animation when the element is added to the DOM.  Nor could I find a way to programmatically set the "begin" attribute or invoke .beginElement() on the animation within the symbol referenced by <use>.  I want to trigger animation only on the newly-added figure, not on all figures.

Is it possible? Or must I dynamically create new animations for every new figure?  Many thanks for any ideas!

I'm using SVG 1.1 on the latest Chrome version.

Bart

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg id="canvas" viewbox="0 0 700 700" version="1.1"
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <defs>
                <symbol id="spot" viewbox="0 0 100 100" >
                    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" >
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                            type="translate" dur="1s" 
                            values="50 50; 25 25; 10 -10; -5 5; 0 0" 
                            keytimes="0; 0.25; 0.5; 0.75; 1" 
                            additive="sum" fill="freeze" />
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML"
                            type="scale" dur="1s" 
                            values="0 0; 0.5 0.5; 0.8 1.2; 1.1 0.9; 1 1" 
                            keytimes="0; 0.25; 0.5; 0.75; 1" 
                            additive="sum" fill="freeze" />
                    </circle>
                </symbol>
            </defs>
        </svg>
            
        <!-- simulate an external event with a timer -->
        <script>
            setTimeout(function() {createNewSpot(200, 200);}, 0);  <!-- this works -->
            setTimeout(function() {createNewSpot(400, 200);}, 1000);  <!-- need to start animation -->
            
            function createNewSpot(x, y) {
                let use = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','use');
                use.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','xlink:href','#spot');
                use.setAttribute("x", x);
                use.setAttribute("y", y);
                use.setAttribute("width", 100);
                use.setAttribute("height", 100);
                use.setAttribute("fill", "red");
                let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                canvas.appendChild(use);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to animate an element without animating all elements then you shouldn't be using use/symbol at all. I.e. if you succeed in animating the symbol it will animate all the use elements that point to it.

Comment: You can begin the SMIL animation whenever you want by using the `beginElement()` method on the animate element `anim.beginElement()` . However since the animation is inside a symbol `beginElement()` will restart the animation in all the symbol's instances

Comment: @RobertLongson then is it a bug that in Firefox a shadowed begin="click" starts only one of the shadow animations? https://jsfiddle.net/Lckbf53q/ (honest question, I'm really lost with the shadow things there and it's actually an interop issue, Chrome restarts all the instances)

Comment: @Kaiido we have some bugs that look similar yes i.e. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=619509 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=595840

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers!  So symbol/use is inappropriate for this case anyway.  I will create a new figure for each instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already creating SVG client-side, you might as well go all the way.

With a Custom Element `<svg-spots>` (supported in all modern browsers) that takes mouse clicks

Do not use Symbols (you can't have duplicate IDs in one document) but create a new `<circle>` with associated animations.

Like enxaneta says in the comments, you need `.beginElement` to restart that (new) animation

```html
<style>
  svg-spots { display: inline-block; width: 100%; background: teal; cursor:pointer }
</style>

<svg-spots></svg-spots>

<script>
  customElements.define('svg-spots', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200"></svg>`;
      this.svg = this.querySelector("svg");
      this.addspot(50, 50, 5, "beige");
      this.onclick = (evt) => {
        let pt = this.svg.createSVGPoint();
        pt.x = evt.clientX;
        pt.y = evt.clientY;
        let click = pt.matrixTransform(this.svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
        this.addspot(click.x, click.y, 3, "gold");
      }
    }
    addspot(x, y, size, color) {
      let id = `id` + x + y;  // unique id for every circle
      let circle = `<circle id="${id}" cx="${x}" cy="${y}" r="${size}" fill="${color}">
         <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="translate" dur="1s" values="50 50; 25 25; 10 -10; -5 5; 0 0" keytimes="0; 0.25; 0.5; 0.75; 1" additive="sum" fill="freeze"/>
         <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="scale" dur="1s" values="0 0; 0.5 0.5; 0.8 1.2; 1.1 0.9; 1 1" keytimes="0; 0.25; 0.5; 0.75; 1" additive="sum" fill="freeze"/>
         </circle>`;
      this.svg.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", circle);
      let animates = this.svg.getElementById(id).querySelectorAll("animateTransform");
      animates.forEach(a => a.beginElement());
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will look into making the figure a custom element for easy instantiation.